# Is it safe to upgrade glibc to 2.2?

Tags: upgrade, games, libraries

I've been looking at purchasing MarbleBlast Gold from [Torque](http://www.torquepowered.com/products/marbleblastgold) and a game called Orbz and one of the requirements is glibc2.2+

I've done a little research around the issue and noticed that Ubuntu uses eglibc,and that glibc is still at version 2.11 in a clean install. However given that the C library is a very important part of the operating system I've been holding off from doing it.

Is it safe to do so without messing up the OS? and if so how would I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2.11 is vastly newer than 2.2 so won't be a problem.

2.11 = two point eleven *not* two point one one.

2.11 > 2.2 in most versioning systems.